# Discord Bot and BeautfiulSoup webscraping project returning maximum recursion depth error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

First time using Stack Overflow, so apologies if this was formatted horrendously.

A few months ago, I decided to start a web scraping project in combination with the discord.py module to generate a set of 3 random songs in Dance Dance Revolution that users can request on Discord. The song names and jacket images were scraped from a rhythm game related website called remywiki. The programming was working fine a while back. However, I'm getting this error now whenever I try to launch the .py file that starts the Discord bot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py", line 412, in __call__
    if frame_cache_key in cache_skips:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Thread 0x00001158 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x00002c34 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x00001340 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x00001454 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x000026ec (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x000010c8 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x000043cc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x00001798 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x000037d4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x00001ffc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 84 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\_threading.py", line 166 in get
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\threadpool.py", line 270 in _worker

Thread 0x0000157c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\libuv\loop.py", line 473 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gevent\hub.py", line 582 in run

Thread 0x000008e0 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 171 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 149 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000014f4 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 168 in recv
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 248 in _read_line
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 262 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 149 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003064 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\queue.py", line 179 in get
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 362 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 149 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00002144 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 113 in _buffered_read_line_as_ascii
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 154 in _wait_for_message
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 272 in process_one_message
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 258 in process_messages
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 521 in process_messages
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00001f0c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 300 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 552 in wait
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\futures.py", line 122 in run_forever
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00001258 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\Kevin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.11.50794\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py", line 412 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 516 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 518 in options
```

Here is the .py file that starts the bot:

```
import discord
import sys
import os
from ritext import img_txt
from song_collector import remy_links, titles
from jacket_collect import*
from jacketcollage import collager, images
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', description = 'A DDR bot that generates memes and songs')
channel = bot.get_channel(594197266668191768)



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} is now online'.format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = '19s with no-bar'))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    user = message.author.name
    msg = message.content
    print(f"{user} said {msg}")

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def randomset(ctx):

    stage_num = 1

    song_set = enumerate(random.sample((img_jacket), k = 3))
    index_num = [jacket[0] for jacket in song_set]
    final_set = [jacket[1] for jacket in song_set]

    print(index_num)
    print(final_set)

    collager(final_set)

    await channel.send(file = discord.File('e.png'))
    os.remove('e.png')

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Random Set", description = "Good luck", color = discord.Color.magenta())

    for index in index_num:
        name = titles[index]
        link = remy_links[index]
        embed.add_field(name = f"Stage #{stage_num}", value = f"[{name}]({link})", inline = False)
        stage_num += 1


    images.clear()
    final_set.clear()
    index_num.clear()
    await ctx.send(embed = embed) 

bot.run('')
```

I believe my error comes somewhere from using BS incorrectly, but I can't figure out where I messed up exactly. Also, I used grequests to help speed up parsing of all the song titles from the website as doing this non-asynchronously would take ages.

Here is part of the code that uses BS. SO doesn't suggest uploading the entirety of my code, but more can be provided upon request.

```
import grequests
import requests
import random
import time
from song_collector import*
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

img_file = []
img_jacket = []
remove_list = []



def jacket():
    index_num = 0

    reqs = (grequests.get(song) for song in remy_links)
    resp = grequests.map(reqs)
    for response in resp:
        soup2 = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        try:
            fileclass = soup2.find('div', class_= 'thumbinner')
            filelink = fileclass.find('a', href = True)
            wrem = remy_url + filelink['href']
            img_file.append(wrem)
            print(wrem)
            index_num += 1
        except AttributeError:
            remove_list.append(index_num)
            index_num += 1
            pass
    for index in remove_list:
        del remy_links[index]
        del titles[index]

def image():

    reqs = (grequests.get(img) for img in img_file)
    resp = grequests.map(reqs)

    for response in resp:
        soup3 = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        try:
            fileclass = soup3.find('div', class_= 'fullImageLink')
            filelink = fileclass.find('a', href = True)
            wrem = remy_url + filelink['href']
            img_jacket.append(wrem)
            print(wrem)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

linklist()
song_title()
jacket()

image()
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you import requests somewhere else before grequests is imported?
This is likely due to [a known issue with grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/issues/103)/[gevent](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016).

Comment: I moved my jacket_collect.py module to the top of my bot file which is the only file with grequests and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much!